# in indices() function gives 'ORA-01722: invalid number' error

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am creating an example that uses `in indices` function in hibernate HQL by following  [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-expressions)

The document has below HQL example:

```
from Show show where 'fizard' in indices(show.acts)
```

So I created an entity for `Show` with a list of `acts` in it like this:

```
@Entity
public class Show {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> acts;

// Getters & Settters
}
```

When I try to execute the HQL mentioned in document then I got the exception as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: unindexed collection before indices() [from Show show where 'fizard' in indices(show.acts)]
```

So to make the collection as indexed I updated my `Show` entity property `acts` like this:

```
@ElementCollection
@OrderColumn
private List<String> acts;
```

After this my program started throwing error as:

```
Hibernate: select show0_.id as id1_2_, show0_.name as name2_2_ from Show show0_ where 'fizard' in (select acts1_.acts_ORDER from Show_acts acts1_ where show0_.id=acts1_.Show_id)

ERROR: ORA-01722: invalid number

Oct 23, 2014 10:12:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at AppTest.showData(AppTest3.java:44)
    at AppTest.main(AppTest3.java:29)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 16 more
```

Here is the program that I am working on:

To save data into DB I have below logic:

```
private static void saveData() {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        List<String> acts = new ArrayList<String>();
        acts.add("fizard");
        acts.add("Lord of Rings");

        Show s = new Show();
        s.setName("One");
        s.setActs(acts);

        List<String> acts1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        acts1.add("Tales");
        acts1.add("Stories");


        Show s1 = new Show();
        s1.setName("Two");
        s1.setActs(acts1);

        session.save(s);
        session.save(s1);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Then to run the HQL I have below logic:

```
private static void showData() {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();

        Query q = session
                .createQuery("from Show show where 'fizard' in indices(show.acts)");
        List<Show> result = q.list();
        System.out.println("result=" + result);
        for (Show p : result) {
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Based on the error, I understand that I am trying to compare a String 'fizard' with indices which is a number. But as I am just following the official hibernate document, can someone please tell me how can I write a simple program using `in indices` function of hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

you queried this:
Hibernate: 
select show0_.id as id1_2_, show0_.name as name2_2_ from Show show0_ 
where 'fizard' in 
(select acts1_.acts_ORDER from Show_acts acts1_ where show0_.id=acts1_.Show_id);

The sense is daubtable, but acts1_.acts_ORDER may be a numeric (eg number) column to get a result like this.